# Rollup wants me to create global variables. How can I use 'export default'?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, rollup

I have a small app I am converting to use rollup. It uses ES6 modules - when I run `rollup -c`, it complains about one of my ES6 modules:

```
/js/monogram.js (imported by src\main.js)
(!) Missing global variable name
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
/js/monogram.js (guessing 'drawMonogram')
created public\js\bundle.js in 311ms
```

The module `monogram.js` uses:

```
export default drawMonogram
```

I am importing it with:

```
import drawMonogram from '/js/monogram.js';
```

Both of these worked before `rollup`. Is this now not OK?

Should I actually make `output.globals` to specify a global name?

Why do I need a global variable? Is the global requirement from ES6 modules (I'd have thought modules would be in a functional scope) or rollup?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Rollup's error is completely unrelated to the problem.** It's simply not able to import the module at that path. Using ES6 modules in browser,

```
import drawMonogram from '/js/monogram.js';
```

Was relative to the web server root. However using `rollup` on the developmnt box,

```
import drawMonogram from '/js/monogram.js';
```

is considered relative to / on the hard disk. Using a relative import fixed the errror.

```
import drawMonogram from './monogram.js';
```

Comment: You saved my night and I'd like to grant you 100 points!! I had `import Collision0 from 'cases/Collision0.svelte';` and starting it with `./cases/...` totally changed the error messages.

Comment: I totally agree: this hint saved me a lot of time looking at the wrong places. The actual problem was: I forgot to install a package from which I was importing. After installing (and restarting sirv because of its caching) everything worked as intended! Thanks a lot!